# Fastest way to match and replace multiple regexes?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

I know there are good ways for replacing fixed string but what is the fastest way to match and replace many regexes when I have millions of strings?

I am currently doing this:

```
class Program 
  {
    static IDictionary<string, string> _map = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
            {"(AM)|(PM)", "<time>"},
            // ... 20 more
            {"\\.[0-9]{3}", "<ms>"},
            {"[a-z0-9]{8}-[0-9a-z]{4}-[0-9a-z]{4}-[0-9a-z]{4}-[0-9a-z]{12}", "<guid>"},
            {"_\\d+_", "_<number>_"}
    };
    static Regex regex = new Regex(String.Join("|", _map.Keys), RegexOptions.Compiled);

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        // for loop for a million strings
        replace("String here");
    }

    public static replace(string str) {
        return regex.Replace(str, m => "<T>")
    }
  }
```

I could not substitute with the string I wanted so am using `<T>`.

Comment: Other than converting your dictionary of strings into a static string (which eliminates `String.Join`), and re-using the `regex` instance, I don't think there is much else you can do.

Comment: You shouldn't be creating the dictionary and the regex on each call to `replace`, that makes no sense if they are fixed. Initialize them as fields outside the method. The `RegexOptions.Compiled` slows the construction of the `Regex` to provide slightly better performance when reused, but the way you are using it now (compiling on each call to `replace`) will tremendously slow down your code.

Comment: Sorry for asking about such detail, but one thing bothers me.. How does the String.Join format a Dictionary? From what I see on MSDN, `Join` takes a string[] or IEnumerable.. so doesn't it pick up a `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,string>>`? IIRC, KVP ToString prints something like `[foo,bar]`.. Does your code shown above produce a reasonable Regex at all? Or is it just a sketch to show the general idea? Or is it some custom String.Join?

Comment: @Groo: I should've clarified that this is just to give an idea. In my code, I am doing the Join only once by making it a static variable. Sorry! Updated my question.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl: Nice catch! It was a typo. It should've been _map.Keys. Updated the questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution for your replacement problem:

```
private static Func<string, string> CreateReplaceFn()
{
    var map = new List<Tuple<string, string>>
    {
        Tuple.Create("AM|PM", "<time>"),
        // ... 20 more
        Tuple.Create("\\.[0-9]{3}", "<ms>"),
        Tuple.Create("[a-z0-9]{8}-[0-9a-z]{4}-[0-9a-z]{4}-[0-9a-z]{4}-[0-9a-z]{12}", "<guid>"),
        Tuple.Create("_\\d+_", "_<number>_")
    };

    var reStr = String.Join("|", map.Select(r => "(" + r.Item1 + ")"));
    var regex = new Regex(reStr, RegexOptions.Compiled);

    return str => regex.Replace(str, match =>
    {
        for (var i = 1; i <= match.Groups.Count; ++i)
        {
            if (match.Groups[i].Success)
                return map[i - 1].Item2;
        }

        return match.Value;
    });
}
```

This function will return a function which will do all the replacements. You have to cache the result of this call and reuse it for your replacements. For instance:

```
var replaceFn = CreateReplaceFn();
foreach (var str in myMilionStrings)
    yield return replaceFn(str);
```

There is one caveat though: You may not use *unnamed* capture groups inside your patterns. If you have to use groups but don't need to capture, replace all `(`...`)` with `(?:`..`)`.

If you really need to use capturing groups inside the patterns, you'll have to *name them* (`(?<name>)` and then `\k<name>` to reference it). This will still work as the named groups will always be last in the `Match.Groups` collection.

Comment: I think he should use `?:` anyways. From what I remember, noncapturing groups are much faster and consume less memory. Of course, it may not be true, I've not checked today on the latest .Net CTP&etc (maybe they are somehow magically lazily evaluated?), but I think that's quite probable guess, since even storing the from-to index ranges take some time..

Comment: @quetzalcoatl yes of course, but my point is that I don't know if he *really* has a need to capture. His example (`(AM)|(PM)` and static replacement strings) led me to assume he doesn't need capture groups inside his patterns.

Comment: If its going to help, I will skip the capture group.

Comment: Sure, the static concatenation really screws up group positioning, heh :) well, unless named groups are used, but again, I dont remember if they got into .Net Regex engine.. blah, sorry, anyways, that was just random thoughts about "millions of strings". For large jobs, probably every little bit is worth considering, so I've dropped a note.

Comment: `AM|PM` => `[AP]M` that is faster.

Comment: @Legend actually I just tested it, named groups are always last in the `Groups` collection (which makes sense), so you're safe if you name all the groups that need capturing: never use plain `(`...`)` in your patterns but replace them with `(?:`...`)` or `(?<something>`...`)` depending on your needs.

Comment: You're welcome. But note I didn't assume this is the fastest way, you should compare this approach to the simpler multiple regex replacements, and use a profiler. I think you'll be the only one able to answer this accurately, because it'll depend on your data and regexes. Mu gut tells me the single regex approach should be faster, but you'd have to test that.